I cannot get drawing to work with wxWidgets
I am trying to make a Snake game. I am able to get the window opened but have had no luck in drawing the grid on to the window.
// Snake.h
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wx/dcbuffer.h>

class Snake : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Snake(const wxString& title);
private:
    void CreateControls();
    void BindEventHandlers();
    
    void OnKeyPressed(wxKeyEvent& evt);
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event);

    void ClosePanel()
    {
        this->Close(); // Close the parent window, which will close the panel
    }

    wxPanel* panel;

};

#include "Snake.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>

Snake::Snake(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title) {
    CreateControls();
    BindEventHandlers();
}

void Snake::CreateControls()
{
    panel = new wxPanel(this);
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(38, 36, 40));
}

void Snake::BindEventHandlers()
{
    panel->Bind(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, &Snake::OnKeyPressed, this); //why did this-> not work? learn hiearchy? because frame did not work?
    this->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &Snake::OnPaint, this);
}

void Snake::OnKeyPressed(wxKeyEvent& evt)
{
    switch (evt.GetKeyCode())
    {
    case WXK_UP:
        break;
    case WXK_DOWN:
        break;
    case WXK_LEFT:
        break;
    case WXK_RIGHT:
        break;
    case WXK_ESCAPE:
        ClosePanel();
        break;
    case WXK_BACK:
        ClosePanel();
        break;
    }
}

void Snake::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    wxBufferedPaintDC dc(this); // Use wxBufferedPaintDC to prevent flickering

    // draw some text
    dc.DrawText(wxT("Testing"), 40, 60);

    // draw a circle
    dc.SetBrush(*wxGREEN_BRUSH); // green filling
    dc.SetPen(wxPen(wxColor(255, 0, 0), 5)); // 5-pixels-thick red outline
    dc.DrawCircle(wxPoint(200, 100), 25 /* radius */);

    // draw a rectangle
    dc.SetBrush(*wxBLUE_BRUSH); // blue filling
    dc.SetPen(wxPen(wxColor(255, 175, 175), 10)); // 10-pixels-thick pink outline
    dc.DrawRectangle(300, 100, 400, 200);

    // draw a line
    dc.SetPen(wxPen(wxColor(0, 0, 0), 3)); // black line, 3 pixels thick
    dc.DrawLine(300, 100, 700, 300); // draw line across the rectangle
}



Unrelated: "trying to learn C/C++ through project-based learning..." Before writing any real/advanced c++ program, it would be better imo to learn c++ first as C++ is one of the most difficult/complicated programming language to learn. Also C++ has the notion of undefined behavior. So we have to be very careful in C++.

I have resolved the issue. Instead of using this-> for Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &Snake::OnPaint, this); I had to use panel->.

@user26867085, this is basic C++ issue - using wrong object. It will be beneficial for you to learn language first. Remember - only the child learn how to speak before learning the alphabet. And I'm hoping you are not that child.

I personally do not like the “you must learn to X before Y” dogma. OP seems to have a fair enough command of what he is doing to have gotten far enough to get his tools together and compile and execute a functioning program. Ignoring his stated problem just to say “you must first reach enlightenment” doesn’t advance anything useful, IMHO.

@Dúthomhas, wxWidgets is an advanced C++ GUI library. I personally don't want to help write code for people who think they know C++ enough to write a good, maintainable code with wxWidgets without a deep C++ knowledge.  Do you?

You're drawing on your frame, but it's entirely covered by your panel. You probably want to draw on the panel, too, i.e. bind to the wxEVT_PAINT on panel, not this.
Note that your paint handler may remain a member of Snake frame, but you still need to draw on the panel inside this, i.e. create a DC associated with the panel and not this inside it too.
